# Discord Bot Command doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, command, bots, discord, roblox

Heyo,

I'm developing a bot mostly about the site Roblox using [roblox-js](https://github.com/sentanos/roblox-js/), though I came across something that doesn't work right.

Groups on that game have a Payout feature, where funds can be seperately given to a player. Funds are made by selling products, clothes, etc. The arguements to call it is:

```
groupPayout(group, member, amount)
```

This can be found [here in the roblox-js wiki git page](https://github.com/sentanos/roblox-js/wiki/Group-Functions#grouppayout)

Here's my code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
if (message.author.bot) return; // Dont panswer yourself.
var args = message.content.split(/[ ]+/)

if(isMessageCommand('pay', message)){
        var username = args[1]
        var groupId = args[2]
        var amount = args[3]
    if (username) if (groupId) if (amount) {
          if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have permissions!")
        message.channel.send(`Paying ${username} ${amount} R$..`)
        roblox.getIdFromUsername(username)
        .then(function(id){
            roblox.getRankInGroup(groupId, id)
            .then(function(amount){
                if(amount < 0){
                    message.channel.send(`You must pay out more than 0 R$!`)
                } else {
                    roblox.groupPayout(groupId, id, amount)
                    .then(function(paid){
                        message.channel.send(`Paid ${username} ${amount} R$!`)
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        //message.channel.send("User cannot be paid out")
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function(err){
                //message.channel.send("Couldn't find user in the group!")
                console.log(err)
            });
        }).catch(function(err){ 
            //message.channel.send(`${username} isn't a valid player!`)
                console.log(err)
        });
    } else {
        //message.channel.send("Please enter a username!")
            console.log(err)
    }
    return;
}
});
```

Basically, the problem is that when I type in the chat

> ;pay MyRobloxUsername GroupID AmountOfRobux

in the output I get:

> Error: You do not have enough in the group fund.
>     at /node_modules/roblox-js/lib/group/groupPayout.js:28:13

and no, that's not exactly what I typed above, just replaced the fields where the information require

**Why doesn't it pay out?**

Comment: You should try printing the error. instead of `"Couldn't find user in the group!"`. do `message.channel.send(err)`

Comment: @Wright 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection                            (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Is that what `err` says or you get that error when trying to do `message.channel.send(err)`

Comment: @Wright I've fixed it by doing console.log(err) and fixed some stuff. The code says I have no funds in my group when I actually do have funds. The bot is attached and logged onto the account that hosts the group. I've updated the code above.

Comment: @Happyyy - so your issue is fixed? If so, can you add your solution as an answer please?